# 'No matching client found' with Flavors in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, android-productflavors

I want to use Flavors for dev and prod, and connect each to a firebase project. I've done the proper setup, but keep getting this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugGoogleServices'. No matching client found for package name 'applicationid.dev'
```

my build.gradle:

```
flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App Dev"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "applicationid"
```

The project exists in firebase, the names match, and I've added google-services.json to the proper folder (app/src/dev/google-services.json)

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
I also tried adding an app inside my main (prod) firebase project, and generating only one google-services.json to manage both. I ran the app as -dev and it ran, but still connected to prod database.

**EDIT 2**
For people running into the same problem, I got it working by deleting google-services.json from app/ root. Leave the google-services files only inside their proper folders in app/src/...

Comment: Consider posting the answer to your question, if you know the answer.